# Simple ADAL.js sample - Userlogin required

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am trying to get a simple adal.js sample to run with a basic asp.net core mvc project (no Authorize attributes). When I run below i am redirected to AAD as expected, i click my user, and then I am shortly redirected back to my page, and then back to the AAD login dialog. I get an "User login required". Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

```
var variables = {
    // Domain of Azure AD tenant
    azureAD: "xx.onmicrosoft.com",
    // ClientId of Azure AD application principal
    clientId: "xx-xx-xx-xx"
}

window.config = {
    tenant: variables.azureAD,
    clientId: variables.clientId,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    endpoints: {
        graphApiUri: "https://graph.microsoft.com"
    },
};
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
var user = authContext.getCachedUser();

if (!user) {
    authContext.login();
}

authContext.acquireToken(config.endpoints.graphApiUri, function (error, token) {
    if (error || !token) {
        console.log("ADAL error occurred: " + error);
        return;
    }
    else {

    }
});
```

Comment: What's the version of ADAL.js are your using ?

Comment: https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.17/js/adal.min.js

Comment: Are the in the same project or is the UI code a separate project from the API?

Comment: It is in the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are not handling the redirect from Azure AD in your application. You will need to call the `handleWindowCallback()` method provided by Adal.js to ensure that the idtoken returned by Azure AD in the redirect URI is parsed and cached to indicate an authenticated user context. 
For a code snippet, take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js#L21-L24) using ADAL.js in a plain Javascript application with an asp.net backend.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated!